# Core Data nullifying existing data when saving new data in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two entities `Work_Shift` and `Driver`. `Work_Shift` and `Driver` have to one relationship from both side. I am saving All data along with `Driver` data in `Work_Shift` entity.

```
-(void)SaveData
{
    NSNumberFormatter *f;
    f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Work_Shift" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //Save new Work Shift Data
    Work_Shift *db_work_shift = [[Work_Shift alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    //Driver entity
    NSEntityDescription *entitydriver = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Driver" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    Driver *db_driver = [[Driver alloc]initWithEntity:entitydriver insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
    db_driver = ((Driver*)[driver_Results objectAtIndex:name_Index]);
    db_work_shift.driver = db_driver;

    NSError *saveError = nil;
    if (![context save:&saveError])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", saveError, [saveError localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

When I save a `Work_Shift` for first time, it inserts the data properly, this is the LOG I am printing for `Driver` id.

```
2013-12-10 18:39:53.039 Mining[868:1803] Work shift count 1
2013-12-10 18:39:55.681 Mining[868:1803] 2013121018395311
2013-12-10 18:39:55.681 Mining[868:1803] Driver id: 1
```

When I insert the `Driver` data again without changing driver details, this is what I get.

```
2013-12-10 18:40:39.747 Mining[868:371b] Work shift count 2
2013-12-10 18:40:42.597 Mining[868:371b] 2013121018395311
2013-12-10 18:40:42.598 Mining[868:371b] (null)
2013-12-10 18:40:42.605 Mining[868:371b] 2013121018403911
2013-12-10 18:40:42.605 Mining[868:371b] 1
```

What I get from this is it is succesfully inserting the new driver but nullifying the last. Same happens when I insert it for the third time. The first 2 are null and 3rd has data.

Is it because of one to one relationship?

Comment: Yes my friend is because the one to one relationship. You need to change to a one to many relationship. Cheers!

Comment: you mean WorkShift to Crew one to Many or Crew to WorkShift one to many?.. But i am inserting a new WorkShift entity every time, why should it play with the previous workShift data? is the issue i am not able to understand. :(

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What type of delete rules you're using?